# How can I add error bars to geom_col in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

How can I add error bars to a geom_col figure in ggplot2? All examples I found googling around are for geom_bar figures. I would like to continue using geom_col rather than convert everything over to geom_bar.

Example

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

beer <- read.csv("http://users.stat.umn.edu/~helwig/notes/MNbeer.csv")

dat <- beer %>%
  group_by(Style) %>%
  summarise(mean_abv = mean(ABV),
            sd_rating = sd(ABV))

ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = dat, aes(x = Style, y = mean_abv),
           position = "dodge", color = "black")

dat$lower <- dat$mean_abv - dat$sd_rating
dat$upper <- dat$mean_abv + dat$sd_rating

#throws error message (Error: geom_errorbar requires the following missing aesthetics: x or y, xmin and xmax)
ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = dat, aes(x = Style, y = mean_abv),
           position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(data = dat, aes(ymin = lower,
                                ymax = upper))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just what the error says: you need also to supply the `x` aesthetic. Try with:

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_col(data = dat, aes(x = Style, y = mean_abv),
           position = "dodge", color = "black") +
  geom_errorbar(data = dat, aes(x=Style, ymin = lower,
                                ymax = upper))
```

As an aside: it is usually not recommended to represent means using columns, you'll probably be better off with points and errorbars.